# yam.platform.setAuthToken no longer working in IE 8 and IE 9

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, yammer

We're currently in the process of integrating Yammer in our corporate SharePoint intranet and for that we use the Yammer Javascript SDK.

When a user accepts our custom Yammer app we store the returned token in the user profile so next time we can use the SDK without the user having to log in again. For subsequent logins, we use the yam.platform.setAuthToken method from the JavaScript SDK.

This used to work in all browsers we use at our company, including IE 8-11 and Chrome. Somehow, it stopped working in IE 8 and IE 9 and we're not sure why.

We've isolated the issue in the following snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" data-app-id="[OUR-APP-ID]" src="https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">   

  $(document).ready(function () {                       
    var $result = $("#result");
    var $details = $("#details");

    try {
      $result.append("running...<br/>");
      yam.platform.setAuthToken("[VALID-USER-TOKEN]", function (response) {
        $result.append("response received...<br/>");
        $details.append("Status: " + response.status + "</br>");
        if (response.authResponse) {
          $result.append("SUCCESS!");
          $details.append("Network name: " + response.access_token.network_name + "</br>");
          $details.append("User ID: " + response.access_token.user_id + "</br>");
          $details.append("Token: " + response.access_token.token + "</br>");
        } else {
          $result.append("FAIL!");
        }
      });    
    } catch (e){
      $result.html("EXCEPTION!");
      $details.html(e);
    }
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Yammer JS SDK</h1>
<div>
  Setting authentication token... Status:<br/> 
  <span id="result" style="color: #00f;">init...<br/> </span>
</div>
<h2>Details:</h2>
<div id="details"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

By using IE 11, you can switch browser versions by using the Dev Toolbar (F12). Switching from IE 11 to 10, 9 and 8, we see that both IE 11 and 10 work OK but IE 9 and 8 fail.

It appears that the ajax-call done by the setAuthToken function fails, but without giving an explanation; it just returns "notConnected". 
We're sure the problem doesn't have to do with the Javascript Origins because these are set correctly in our app configuration and the above snippet works flawlessly in IE 10, IE 11 and Chrome.

Did Yammer update their SDK, removing support for IE 8 and IE 9 or are we missing something here? Please help us!

Answer (score 0):

Atleast for IE 8 support from Yammer is Dec 14. please refer "Supported Browsers": https://developer.yammer.com/upgrading-to-the-new-yammer-js-sdk/ and 
http://community.office365.com/en-us/w/yammer/yammer-internet-explorer-support-update-123114.aspx